# tailwind card collapses with small change in height

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm new to Tailwind and trying to make a card.

The code works but when I change the `height` to `50` or anything other than close to `60` the entire container collapses? What's causing this and how to deal with it?

```js
/* added by Editor for demonstration purpose */
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var h = document.querySelector('.relative');
  h.classList.toggle('h-50');
  h.classList.toggle('h-60');
});
```

```css
/* added by Editor for demonstration purpose */
button {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tailwind -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Button added by Editor for demonstration purpose -->
<button>Toggle Height</button>

<!-- Body -->
<div class="mx-auto px-4">
  <div class="relative w-75 h-60 bg-neutral-500 rounded-2xl truncate border-solid border-indigo-400 border-2">
    <div class="absolute w-20 top-0 left-0 group-hover:inset-y-4">
      <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/running_shoes/running_shoes_PNG5782.png" alt="nike-air-shoe" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the classes defined in TailwindCSS near `h-50` in height are `h-48`, `h-52`,`h-56`and `h-60`. So whenever you give height like `h-49` or `h-51` it will give default `h-0 height` and thus collapses.

You can check all the height dimensions [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height) .

If you want to give a custom height, you can give it by `h-[50px]` or `h-[50rem]`.